# Adding Metadata to images for sharing on android

Tags: java, android, android-sharing

I am trying to add metadata to an image within an android application. 
The application receives the image from the gallery, and can successfully forward it on using a share button. What I am struggling to do, however, is to add metadata to the image. I just need to add some simple data (mainly the description).

```
oid handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

    if (imageUri != null) {
         Bitmap myBitmap;

        try {
            myBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap,
                    myBitmap.getWidth() / 4, myBitmap.getHeight() / 4,
                    false);
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);


            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            myImage.refreshDrawableState();


            Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (myBitmap != null) {
                        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        share.setType("image/jpeg");
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                                bytes);
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "myfirstpicture.jpg");
                        values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                                "A pretty picture");
                        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                        values.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
                        values.put(Images.Media.DATA, bytes.toByteArray());
                        // Uri i =

                        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(
                                getApplicationContext()
                                        .getContentResolver(), myBitmap,
                                "pic.jpg", "a pretty picture");
                        Uri i = Uri.parse(path);

                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, i);

                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,
                                "Share Image"));
                    } else {
                        //Display message
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to send the image, but the metadata is lost and the title reset to a timestamp. 
I have tried using a different URI

```
  Uri i = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

But this results in the application crashing (logcat below).

I have looked around a lot but I have not been able to find anything that has worked.

Help is much appreciated

Update: Logcat error for alternate URI

```
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create new file: [B@426df408
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1439)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:440)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:917)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.bham.cs.blindrouting.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:128)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18795)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
05-21 15:44:11.270: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post logcat error message...

Comment: what is on `MainActivity.java:128` ?

Comment: That is the alternate URI:
Uri i =getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);